# Should I use Quartz or Open GL ES for my drawing app? Or both of them combined?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, drawing, quartz-graphics

This is my first iPhone/iPad app :S

It is a drawing app and I would like that user could save the current work and after that continue drawing on that same image (updating).

I already did something based on [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/iPhone/iOSGetStarted01.aspx) and [this](http://www.ifans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=132024). This uses Quartz.
So I would have to save it to some format that can be read back into the memory and displayed on the screen for updating (user draws another line or erases some before).

The images would be saved on server and I would like it to be in a format that in future Android devices also can read it (just read it, not update).

Also, a lot of transformations is going to be on that images after they are finished drawing (scale, projection...). I found that Open GL ES is great for this transformations --> [Open GL ES](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3664/opengl-es-2-0-for-iphone-tutorial)

**So the question is**,

should I use Quartz for drawing since it is simple and convert the image somehow to Open GL because Open GL is good for transformations? And in which format to save the drawing so it could be used latter for updating and that Android devices could also read it?

Comment: While it is probably more difficult to do the drawing in OpenGL than Quartz, it is probably still easier than finding a way to convert to OpenGL(if it is even possible, I'm not sure either, but I doubt it).  Not really sure about the other part.

Comment: @turboSwag The only reason I am thinking about OpenGL is because of the transformations. And I think that it could be easier to save it in format for later Android usage.

Comment: OpenGL is definitely more robust, but the only way you could really convert from quartz would be to store points and pass them asa vertices in OpenGL, at which point it would probably be easier to just use OpenGL in the first place. Really, it sounds like trying to use Quartz would add an unnecessary step.

Comment: It looks like that, yes.

Answer (score 0):

To port to android latter Quartz won't help you, openGL is faster, in this case more portable and great for transformations (and effects, even better with ES 2.0 and shaders).

However if you haven't used openGL yet it's quite a different journey from quartz, so maybe read some tutorials on programming in openGL first to get a fell for it.